# c allocated memory without knowing the length

Tags: c

I'm new with c programming, i'm trying to allocate memory without knowing the length, i want someone to write and when he end just push enter while(c != '\n')
but i don't know how to this.

```
puts("Enter a text, when you done write the e then enter: ");
char *arr = (char*)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
while (getchar != EOF)
{
    if(arr == NULL)
    { 
        printf("Error: memory not allocated \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    arr[count] = getchar();
    arr = realloc(arr, count + 1);
}
return arr;
```

Comment: You really don't want to do that one character at a time. Better practice is to allocate a larger block and resize only when you're getting towards its max size. Keep in mind that allocation from the OS is in pages that are typically 4KB or 8KB in size.

Comment: Also, `getchar != EOF` is comparing the *function* getchar, not its return value. The function itself will never be equal to `EOF`.

Comment: Also, You need count up `count` and Finally add NUL(`'\0'`).

Comment: regarding: `char *arr = (char*)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));` 1) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) the returned value has type `void*`.  So it can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: this statement: `while (getchar != EOF)` and `arr[count] = getchar();`  should be (respectively) `int ch; while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF)`  and `arr[count] = ch;`

Comment: regarding: `puts("Enter a text, when you done write the e then enter: ");`  This is a very confusing prompt to the user.  Perhaps you meant: `puts("Enter a text, when you done click: <enter>: ");`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error: memory not allocated \n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  A much better statement would be: `perror( "malloc failed" );`  Which would also output the reason the OS thinks the error occurred.

Comment: when calling `realloc()`: Do NOT directly assign the returned value to the target pointer.   If `realloc()` fails, then the pointer to the original allocation is lost (a memory leak)  Suggest: char *temp = realloc(arr, count + 1);  if (!temp) { perror( "realloc failed" ); free( arr );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }  arr = temp;`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution *EDIT: if you have POSIX* is to use the `getline` function, which allocates memory automatically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* ... other stuff here ... */

char *buffer = NULL;
size_t bufsize = 0;
ssize_t chars_read;

/* optional: set bufsize to something positive, then set buffer = malloc(bufsize); */

chars_read = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);

/* do stuff with buffer */

free(buffer);
```

`getline` will enlarge its buffer whenever necessary using `realloc`, so you don't need to handle any of that yourself. Here I started it with a size of zero so that it'll do the initial `malloc` for me too! But you can also give it your own allocated buffer, and just let `getline` enlarge it if necessary.

After calling `getline`, `chars_read` will hold the total number of characters read, including the trailing newline. If this is `-1` then something went wrong, such as end-of-file or failure to allocate memory. `bufsize` will hold the new size of `buffer`, which may or may not have changed.

See [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) for more information.

Comment: Note that `getline()` is standardized by POSIX (since 2008), but it is not part of the ISO C language standard.  It is indeed convenient for the kind of thing the OP wants to do, but it might not be a viable choice, depending on where he wants his code to work.